# Undefined reference to `rindex_`

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have a code in Fortran 77 (*. f). I use the compiler fort77 but it gives me the following error:

```
   geodv.o: In function `main__ ':
   fort77-10104-1.c: (. text +0 x287): reference to `rindex_ 'undefined
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code can be found [at this dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1c9ke75bruqf94n/geodv.f). Thank you for your help

Comment: rindex is an extension supported by some compilers.  (obviously available to whoever wrote the code).  You can write your own in about 10 lines using index()

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `rindex` to be an `integer*4` on line 15, but use it as `nd2=rindex(entete,'/')` in line 62. Fortran expects line 62 to mean that `rindex` is a function, not an integer.

Comment: Hello, a question
¿How can I make  the change to identify which is a function?
thank you!!

Comment: If `rindex` is supposed to be a function, you need to define that function in the code, just as you did with `ichy` (line 494) and `today` (line 454).

Comment: there was an error in the code, because my teacher mistyped the code.
rindex = index
But in the a.out displays an error:

list in: end of file
apparent state: internal I / O
direct reading lately formatted internal IO
aborted

Comment: you think? looking at the code it seems quite unlikely he meant to call index twice in a row with the same arguments.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        nd1 = index(entete,'/')
    nd2 = index(entete(nd1+1:),'/')+nd1
```

note this will give the position of the second '/' , not the last, so it is the same only if your string has just two '/'s..

Comment: Hello.
I tried the change, I get a.out, put the command . / a.out and I find the following:
list in: end of file
apparent state: internal I / O
direct reading lately formatted internal IO
aborted

Comment: my guess your string doesnt hold a date as expected. put write(\*,\*)nd1,nd2,entete right after the above lines.